# Run sql - mysql - code everytime my page is updated

Tags: php, mysql

Were in my php code do I have to put this lines:

```
**$sql = ''
    . ' ALTER TABLE `equipos5a6f`'
    . ' ORDER BY `ganados` DESC';**
```

In order to make that happen everytime the page is refreshed.

Comment: What does this have to do with phpmyadmin?

Comment: i copied that code from phpmyadmin...from generate php code when running the sql query.... i just keep editing sql order and it stays the same, so i have to find out a way to execute that code everytime my page is refreshed

Comment: you should add order by in queries, this *wont* guarantee a certain order for a query on the equipos5a6f table, where order is not specified in the query

Answer (score 2):

Any performance boost you get from the `ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY` statement is going to be negated by running it every page request.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to make a connection to your database (depend on wich database you are using : phpMyAdmin, EasyPHP, Oracle...)
And then make a request. 
I suggest you to look at this website.

[How to make a connection and request with PHP to MySQL](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/connect-to-mysql-database.aspx)

Maybe it will be more clear

Good Luck!